# Use of the subfiles package results in a compilation error, due to the compiler erroneously parsing a commented-out "\end{document}"

Tags: compiling, subfiles

I have the following two files in a folder:

`mymainfile.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}
%\end{document}
\subfile{mysubfile.tex}
\end{document}
```

`mysubfile.tex`:

```
\documentclass[mymainfile.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}
```

Compiling `mymainfile.tex` (using pdflatex) works fine, and includes the contents of `mysubfile.tex`, as it should. However, compiling `mysubfile.tex` on its own leads to the following error description:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.3 h
     ello
?
```

I.e. the compiler acts just as if the line

```
%\end{document}
```

wasn't commented out. If this line is removed, both files compile fine.

The fact that the compiler reads the commented-out line as if it wasn't a comment at all makes me very uneasy, I thought the fact that comments are consistently ignored by the compiler was the ONE thing I could always count on! What might be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, it seems like a definite bug in the `subfiles` package.
I can only assume that the subfiles package have their own code for parsing the main document, which doesn't have full, proper, latex-parsing.

In fact, I would argue that it should compile fine even if it correctly parses `\end{document}`, since it should only really need the header from `mymainfile.tex` and should therefor stop at the first (uncommented) line with `\begin{document}`.